# Issue with custom controls in fullscreen (chrome mobile)

Tags: html5-video

I'm trying to make custom controls. I've hidden the original with

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display:none !important;
}
```

This is the HTML of video block

```
<div id="video-container">
  <video width="400px" src="#" id="video"></video>

  <div id="controls">
    <div class="switch" id="play"></div>
    <div id="progress">
      <div id="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="fullscreen"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS of controls

```
#controls {
  z-index: 2147483647;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: silver;
  display: flex;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

This is toggleFullscreen function in JS

```
if((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||
(!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
    if (video.requestFullscreen) {
        video.requestFullscreen();
    }
    else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        container.mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
    }
    else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        video.webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
    }
}
else{
    if(document.cancelFullScreen) {
        document.cancelFullScreen();
    }
    else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    }
    else if(document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
}
```

So, when I open desktop Chrome it's working fine. Going fullscreen, it's OK. I press f12, "toggle device toolbar", choose any phone, go fullscreen, it's there. I turn landscape mode, nothing bad there.
Then I open it on my phone. I see it. I go fullscreen, Aaaand I see it. "But what's the problem?" Will you ask?
You see, `src="#"`? With my js I change it `$video.attr("src", dir);`
Now it's gone. No controls in fullscreen. While the original controls will be seen, if I enable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I managed it. I was applying fullscreen to the video, now I do this for video-container (which contains video and controls).

Thank you for attention.